# I want to show my ylim in the actual number, not the le8

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

This is my code and the result I get, the ylim isn't in the form I want!!! [image]

This is the ylim form that I want it to be!! [image]

Comment: `ax = sns.regplot(...)` and `ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')` should work

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```py
ax = sns.regplot('sqft_above', 'price', data=df)
ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain')
```

This will set the "style" of the tick labels to be plain, removing the scientific formatting.